# multi tags using auto suggest jQuery plugins

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use Auto suggest jQuery plugins from this site:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

for making tags multiple as like giving in that site.

But my problem is...
While selecting from the autosuggest, it was displayed in my input box but I don't want to display selected autosuggest again as like in example given in the link....but I am unable to do such things...

please help me...
code used by me as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view/stylesheet/autoSuggest.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/jquery/jquery.autoSuggest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

$("#product_tag1").autoSuggest("http://test.com/ajax", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true,selectedItemProp: "tag", searchObjProps: "tag"});

//--></script>
```

Ajax file like

```
<?

$input = $_GET["q"];

$data = array();


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field LIKE '%$input%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

$json = array();

$json['tag_id'] = $row['id'];

$json['tag'] = $row['tag'];



$data[] = $json;

}

header("Content-type: application/json");

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: I got solution and it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the [Select 2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) plugin as an alternative? It is in active development and has IMHO nicer features; for example showing the list of available tags when the control has focus and not allowing the same tag to be selected more than once.

It sounds like it will do exactly what you want, but please see the [Tagging Example](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#tags) for a  description of all of the options. I do not think it will be difficult to switch plugins, based on your example code.

Answer (score 0):

By using following codes in document ready function of javascript

$(document).ready(function()

    {

 var data=null;  

    

 var data=;

     

 $("#tag").autoSuggest("config->item('admin_folder').'/products/autosuggest');?>",{minChars: 2, matchCase: true,selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name",selectedValuesProp:"value",preFill: data});    

    });